# Python Kivy: self.ids not updating label text

Tags: python, kivy, label

I want to update the text in a label every second using the Kivy Clock.

When the button in 'TimeDisplay' is pressed, I want the class 'Display' to be called by the Clock and update the text in the Label in 'Display' each time it is called.

Here's my Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import time
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import threading
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Window.size = (600, 400)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):  # class used for transitions between windows
   pass

class TimeDisplay(Screen):
   def on_press(self):
       display = Display()
       Clock.schedule_interval(display.display_time, 1)

class Display(Screen):
   def display_time(self, *args):
       print(self.ids)
       self.current_time = StringProperty()
       self.current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") #provides local time as a structure format of minutes followed by seconds
       self.ids.time.text = str(self.current_time)


class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       layout = Builder.load_file("layout.kv")  # loads the kv file
       return layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
   MyApp().run()
```

And here's the kivy code:

```
WindowManager:
#sets up the different screens for the app and the default order that they run in
    transition: NoTransition() #sets all transitions as 'NoTransition'
    TimeDisplay:
    Display:
    #AlarmDisplay:


<Button>:
    background_normal: "" #sets all buttons default background colour to white


<TimeDisplay>
    Button:
        opacity: 0
        on_press:
            root.on_press()
            root.manager.current = "display"

<Display>
    name: "display"

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            id: time
            color: (1,0.5,0.5,1)
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            opacity: 1
            text: ""
            font_size: 35
            color: ((83/255),(83/255),(83/255),1) #sets the colour of the text (rgba)
```

Why does the `self.ids.time.text` not update the text of the label with id `time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of code in your `on_press()` method:

```
   display = Display()
```

creates a new instance of the `Display` class. This new instance is not the instance that appears in your GUI, so any changes that you make to it will not appear in your GUI. You must reference the instance of `Display` that is actually in your GUI. You can do that by replacing the above line with:

```
display = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('display')
```